# While-loop evaluation condition

Tags: c++, while-loop

Sorry if the question seems really trivial but I'm just learning how to code and this one kept me in front of the computer for about 2 hours without getting to realize why this happens.

I'll pass the code below.
So, in order to keep it straightforward:

*isPrime()* is a function that just checks if a current number is Prime or not.

*nPrime()* is a function that returns the n-ism prime number, given N as the parameter.

The key point here is the main function and, more precisely, the **number value** in the **first while-loop**.

If you run this code, when it reaches the last prime number by which *number* is divisible, it'll enter an infinite loop. This can be easily solved if you just change the first while condition from **while(number > 0)** to **while(number > 1)**.

That's the weird thing I can't come to realize:
If the **inner second while-loop** won't exit as long as **number % nPrime(index) != 0** and the last instruction of the **outter first while-loop** is **number /= nPrime(index);**, how come the program enters an infinite loop?

That last instruction set number's value to 0, so the first while-loop condition should return **false** and exit the loop.

What am I missing?

Thank you all for your time and patience.

PS: I got downvoted and I don't know why, so I'll make an clarification:

I've done the research. As far as I know, every source seems to agree on the same point:

**the > condition returns true if and only if left operand is greater than right operand**.

Which takes me to the previously written question: if *number* is **equal** to 0, how's the while-loop not evaluating the **number > 0** as **false** and exiting from the iteration?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int);
int nPrime(int);


int main() {


    int number = 264;

    if (number > 0)
    {
        int index = 1;

        while(number > 0)
        {
            while (number % nPrime(index) != 0)
            {
                index++;
            }
            cout << nPrime(index) << endl;
            number /= nPrime(index);
        }

    }

    else
        cout << "Error";


    return 0;
    }


bool isPrime(int n)
{
    bool isPrime = false;
    int totalDividends = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
                totalDividends++;
        }


    if(totalDividends == 2)
         isPrime = true;

    return isPrime;
}

int nPrime(int n)
{
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        do
        {
            result++;
        } while (!isPrime(result));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is likely here: `while (number % nPrime(index) != 0)`. It's hard to get out of `1% anything_but_1`. Stepping through your code with the debugging software that comes with virtually all development environments will prove me right or wrong.

Comment: Unrelated: Perform a websearch for Prime Number Sieve to find a much faster method for computing prime numbers.

Comment: I second the debugger!

Comment: You're totally right. That was exactly the thing I was missing. Thank you guys for the help. 

Also, I've checked Sieve's Prime Numbers Method: it's really good and very interesting!

Lastly, I've just downloaded VSCode instead of sublime in order to have a simple Debugger, all advises have been very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Read the VS Code documentation closely. Stack Overflow is gathering quite a collection of questions from folk who haven't configured it correctly. Looks like it's  going to be a decent tool, but it's new and still somewhat picky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing?
>
> That last instruction set number's value to 0

No it doesn't, it never gets that far. When number equals one then `number % nPrime(index) != 0` is always true, so the inner while loop never exits.

Your understanding of while loops is perfect, it's your understanding of what your own code does that is in error. This is normal for bugs like this.

Comment: Indeed, the real problem here was that, after the last instruction, the value of number was equal to 1. 

Then, when passing the function nPrime(1) it will divide it by 2, the first prime number, instead of 1, and the condition will always result true. 

Pretty well explained, thank you very much John.